# What is an attacker looking for when they try to get me to go to their website?

Tags: scam

This is the third time I've gotten a call from someone asking me to just go to their website so that we can talk about the information [stock, forex and/or crypto trading] there.

Many things that were said in the conversation triggered red flags for me and I'm sure that they are trying to con me in some way or another.

- They deflected each time I tried to ask for the domain.
- "This is not a finical trading site sir, you don't need to do research."
- "You don't have time to do research."
- "You don't need to do the research ahead of time, we will do the research together."

What con could this person be trying to do? Could the con be me making a request to their site (and them using a vulnerability) or are they going to expose it later after I've been on their site?

If I wanted to "play" along, what security tools should I be using before making a request to this site?

*Can my personal information be gained or my device compromised if going to a requested site?
Is there any protections I can install or download  to reduce such risks?

Comment: The edit doesn't make it more answerable. The answer is "it depends on the site".

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that they have browser exploits or other things on their site, but cold calling people to try and deliver them is a rather convoluted way to do that. It's much more likely to just be a scam to steal your personal information/bank/card details once they've got you on their site and convinced you to buy into whatever kind of magic beans they're selling.